# How to use cusom fonts with the Raspberry Pi (using Qt Quick)?

Tags: gui

I'm using EGLFS for graphics (via Qt Quick), and the only font there seems to exist is a very ugly serif font.

I downloaded `OpenSans`, copied it into `usr/local/share/fonts`, but it doesn't work. Copying the same `ttf` files into the same folder on a Debian PC works fine.

```
Text { font.family: "OpenSans"; text: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" }
```

I tried several well-known font names which are included in almost any system, without success.

I also tried the suggestions found at [Qt for Embedded](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qt-embedded-fonts.html), but `/lib/fonts` also didn't work.

I use the default Raspbian which came pre-installed with the devoce.

Interestingly, the xserver on my Pi uses a sans-serif font for its GUI. However, I guess it does not have much to do with my problem, as my GUI application works properly even if the xserver is not started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to embed the fonts into the application.
Put a `FontLoader` fairly early into the main application window, for example:

```
FontLoader {id: customName; source:"qrc:///fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"}
```

And use it later:

```
Text { font.family: customName.name; text: "xyz" }
```

One disadvantage is that if you have multiple applications using it, you have to embed the fonts into each of them.